# How to solve an equation containing logarithm functions with different bases

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I was studying for a math test when I encountered a problem I had trouble solving in my study guide.

Solve for $x$:

$\log_bx+c\log_ax=d$

I began by changing the bases, but I don't know how to proceed further. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Change to a common base, like $e$: $\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(b)}+c\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(a)}=d$. Then $\ln(x)=\frac{d}{\frac{1}{\ln(b)}+c\frac{1}{\ln(a)}}$. Lastly, take $\exp(\cdot)$ on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to do a change of base:
\begin{align*}\log_bx+c\log_ax&=d \\
\dfrac{\ln x}{\ln b} + c\frac{\ln x}{\ln a} &= d \\
\ln x\cdot\left(\frac1{\ln b}+\frac c{\ln a}\right) &= d \\
\ln x&=\frac d{\frac1{\ln b}+\frac c{\ln a}} \\
x&=\boxed{e^{\frac d{\frac1{\ln b}+\frac c{\ln a}}}}.\end{align*}
Where $\ln$ is log base $e$. You can change it to any other base if it suites your purpose.